# Find for the maximum occurrences of a particular pattern appearing consecutively within a substring [Python]

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Suppose I want to find a pattern AAGTC in a string `AGTCAAGTCAAGTCAAGTCXYZSDAAGTCAAGTC` and return the maximum times AAGTC occurs consecutively (3).

I'm trying to do the following -
Find all occurrences using re-find all
define a variable m = sum of all occurrences

Then I'm trying to iterate from m till match found for `AAGTC{m}` using re.search. But it's not working? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 5 "AAGTC" in your string but they are not consecutive. You can try to start from m and decrease it till you don't find match.

```
>>> "AGTCAAGTCAAGTCAAGTCXYZSDAAGTCAAGTC".count("AAGTC")
5
>>> ("AAGTC" * 3) in "AGTCAAGTCAAGTCAAGTCXYZSDAAGTCAAGTC"
True
>>> ("AAGTC" * 4) in "AGTCAAGTCAAGTCAAGTCXYZSDAAGTCAAGTC"
False
```

Comment: worked like a dream! thats the most pythonic way! thanks!!